# Stored procedure MySQL 5.5.16

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So I have in my database a table called "weeks" where I store every weeks of the years like so:

`table weeks(id, year, num_week, date_min, date_max)`

So for this week, the line look like this :
[image: week 36]

**Note** : My weeks starts on thursday and ends on Wenesday.

Since it is a pain inserting each weeks line by line, I want to create a stored procedure for this, here's what I came up with :

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_insert_weeks()

BEGIN

SELECT year, num_week, date_min, date_max INTO @year, @num_week, @date_min, @date_max
FROM weeks
ORDER BY date_min DESC LIMIT 1;

SET @date_min = DATE_ADD(@date_max INTERVAL 1 DAY);
SET @date_max = DATE_ADD(@date_min INTERVAL 6 DAY);
SET @year= YEAR(@date_min);

IF @num_week < 52 THEN SET @num_week = @num_week + 1;
ELSE SET @num_week = 1;
END IF;

INSERT INTO weeks (year, num_week, date_min, date_max)
VALUES (@year, @num_week, @date_min, @date_max);

END |

DELIMITER ;
```

So the idea was to take the last record of the table and add 1 week to the dates, but I can't even make it paste the creation of the procedure.

I get an error right after the SELECT query, can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop PROCEDURE proc_insert_weeks;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_insert_weeks()

BEGIN

SELECT year, num_week, date_min, date_max INTO @year, @num_week, @date_min, @date_max
FROM weeks
ORDER BY date_min DESC LIMIT 1;

SET @date_min = DATE_ADD(@date_max, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
SET @date_max = DATE_ADD(@date_min, INTERVAL 6 DAY);
SET @year= YEAR(@date_min);

IF @num_week < 52 THEN SET @num_week = @num_week + 1;
ELSE SET @num_week = 1;
END IF;

INSERT INTO weeks (year, num_week, date_min, date_max)
VALUES (@year, @num_week, @date_min, @date_max);

END |

DELIMITER ;
```

You can try above code.

You made mistake in [`DATE_ADD`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_add-function.php) function. You missed `,` in it.

Comment: Thanks it is working now ! I'll accept this answer as soon as I can